# Build Mobile Apps for Enterprise uses only

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We are going to build Mobile apps to access the data inside of firewall for our employees to use. We have the skill to build hybrid apps.  We are looking for a solution to be able to authenticate users to use the apps. Below is the ideal solution.

1. Can we upload our apps to a private app store to allow only our employee to download for both iOS and Android users?
2. How to access the database inside the intranet?
3. How do we authenticate our users? (use Single Sign On) either authenticated by our mobile app or 3rd party software. (like GOOD)

Does anyone here know any platform or product we can use? Any suggestions?  Thank you very much.

Comment: I've made something similar these days. I don't know if they're the best practices, but: (2) I've done it by GET and POST requests to a java server. (3) Search for authentication tokens. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to know the options for question #1.

As far as authentication and access to intranet data....
Something will have to be exposed to the internet that will allow access to your data.  This can be accomplished by writing a node express server that acts as a proxy to your data.  The node server can also handle the authentication before serving up the data using jwt (JSON Web Tokens).  You can find and example here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens